# Dual Boot - How to access Windows partition without having to shut down Windows

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows

Currently, when I restart from Windows to Ubuntu, or if I hibernate Windows and boot Ubuntu, I can't access my Windows partition.

I have to restart from Ubuntu to Windows, then shut down Windows, then boot Ubuntu again.

Is there another way around this?

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/user/Windows8_OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/user/Windows8_OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Windows (since version 7 or 8?) uses FastBoot to speed up its boot process. Therefore it uses kind of hibernation, which keeps the partition in an "in use"-state somehow and prevents Ubuntu having full access on it.

Solution: Just disable the FastBoot option in Windows!

Comment: I have actually disabled that a long time ago. Hmm.

Comment: Strange. Better check it again (sometimes updates etc do stuff they shouldn't...)! Could you also describe in more detail what error messages you get when you try to mount/access the partition (and how)? Thank you.

Comment: I updated my original post with the error message. I am accessing the Windows partition directly through the Files explorer (or whatever it's called) of Ubuntu.

Comment: The file browser of Unity is called Nautilus. And according to the error message, it IS a problem with hibernation/FastBoot! Did you check it again? You should be able to mount the drive read-only anyways, if that would be enough for you.